# Validating HTML form using Javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am having a script which validates a user's name. When the user enters name without spaces then it works fine. If user enters name with spaces (name, surname, lastname etc) then it is not working. I am trying to capture 'space' character using `\s` but it is not working.

My script is:

```
var name=document.forms["newform"]["fullname"].value; //get the name from HTML form
var charpos = name.search("[^A-Za-z\s]");
if (name.length <= 0 || name.length>=50 || charpos >= 0)
{
    alert('wrong.');
}
else
{
     alert('correct');
}
```

Input1: **AFGH**

Output1: **correct**

Input2: **ABCD EFGH**

Output2: **wrong**

When Input2 is given, `charpos` gets the value '5'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string literal is swallowing the `\`.

You should use a regex literal:

```
name.search(/[^A-Za-z\s]/);
```

Comment: Thanks SLaks. It worked!! Can you please explain a little how string literal is swallowing the ` \ `? What swallowing means? Thanks again.

Comment: @iSumitG, `\ ` is an escape in regular strings, if you want the character it self to be present in the string, you have to escape it, eg `"[^A-Za-z\\s]"`.